# Linux - change the hostname in the CLI

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, fedora

I don't know how to search for this and that is why I asked for it (all my searches did not reveal any relevant information).

I have a Fedora 18 server that looks like this:

```
[root@dhcp-192-168-5-100 ~]#
```

I want to change that to:

```
[root@server1 ~]#
```

Currently, this machine is set to get IP through DHCP, but that is not the IP address of the machine and that is why I need to change the CLI to something more relevant.

Thank you

Comment: are you just trying to change the appearance of your command line prompt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can type "hostname HOSTNAME" where HOSTNAME is the new name you want.  The next time you log in / connect via ssh, that's what you'll see.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. And to make it permanent I need to change the hostname of the PC altogether, right?

Comment: yes Enobe's comment below would make it permanent (ie stays after reboot)

Comment: It did't stay after reboot. I changed the HOSTNAME in /etc/.../network, but after reboot I still have "root@dhcp-...". I think I need to change something else also, but what?

Comment: i think you will need to either use a static ip address or talk to whoever administers your DHCP server.

Comment: The hostnamectl command can be used to make the changes permanent (don't need to edit any config files). Thank you

Comment: After making this change, in my case, the sudo command started to return `sudo: unable to resolve host NEW-NAME` whenever I use it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/network` and change/add HOSTNAME variable like so `HOSTNAME=server1.domain.com` After restart it should have server1.
2. Edit /etc/hosts and add `server1` and `server1.domain.com` to 127.0.0.1 line, so it will look like: `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost server1 server1.domain.com`

More about network file you can read here:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-The_sysconfig_Directory.html#s2-sysconfig-network

Comment: It's not permanent, after reboot it's back to "root@dhcp...". Is there some other file I need to change?

Comment: You might need to change `/etc/hosts` file 127.0.0.1 line too, similar to: `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost server1 server1.domain.com` So make both changes and restart.

Comment: I found another command to do this: hostnamectl and with it you can make the changes permanent. I will mark Joe T response as the answer because it was the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this and this is described pretty good.

```
   [root@dhcp-192-168-5-100 ~]# hostname MYHOSTNAME
```

[Change hostname in Feodora](http://www.labtestproject.com/using_linux/permanently_change_hostname_on_fedora)

Comment: I found a lot of info about changing the hostname, I did not know that changing the hostname would also change how the CLI appears. And I saw on some other sites that the CLI hostname was not changed when the hostname was changed, that is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add "yournewhostname" into /etc/sysconfig/network in the HOSTNAME
   field..
2. Add "yournewhostname" into /etc/hosts for 127.0.0.1
3. echo "yournewhostname" > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname or service hostname

IMPORTANT: logout and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

It can be changed by following below steps:

- sudo hostname
- sudo nano /etc/hosts
- change the old host i.e. in front of 127.0.1.1 to the new host like below
- 127.0.1.1
- sudo nano /etc/hostname
- change oldhostname to
- reboot